# google translator django moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'translate'

Tags: python, django

hi everybody i make a django quiz project and i want to add advantge google translate to a page i download the pakge by

```
pip install django-google-translate
```

i add google-translate to my setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'google_translate',
```

in template i wrote

```
{% load google_translate %}
```

i make that with the instructon of this page
[django-google-translate 1.1](https://pypi.org/project/django-google-translate/)
in terminal i got the message

```
Cannot import 'translate'. Check that 'google_translate.apps.TranslateConfig.name' is correct.
```

who can i solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit <django-google-translate installed folder>/apps.py and in class **TranslateConfig**, change the 'name = *translate*' to *google_translate*.